# my featured image of wordpress are not showing in the front end though image are uploaded in media library

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

my featured image of wordpress here https://share-ask.com/about-robin-uthapa/ are not showing in the front end though image are uploaded in media library .

can any1 help.

When i upload new image & set it as featured image it works but old images doesnt worked

Also my old files in upload folder are not showing me in media library

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a lazy load plugin for performance, hiding the images out of the viewport and it doesn't work as expected. You can try by disabling it.

Comment: Tnx i disabled plugin but it doesnt fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

It's two years since this question was asked but did you solve the problem? I encountered a similar situation after changing Web servers/hosting. There were two main problems.

First, permissions are set at 0644 when uploaded through the Wordpress interface. If you have access to the server, recursively set all files under the Uploads folder to 0644.

Secondly, the meta info of the images can be somehow mis-set. There's a plugin called **Media Sync** that you can use to scan your uploads directory for misconfigured image file paths and correct them.

After examining those two possibilities and if they correct your issue, you can go to the editor and set the featured image(s) from already uploaded files in the media library. There's a plugin called **Featured Image Plus** that allows setting the featured image from the quick edit function of the posts list, which in my experience, saves time from the hassle of sevetal trips to the editor.

HTH.